# Searching Inside a Document for Multiple Strings with 'GREP'

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to search inside a word document for strings with specific text. So far, I have figured out how to search inside this document for a single string and return a message if this text is found using the below script. The challenge that I am now facing is figuring out how to search inside this document for either one of two strings.

Any idea of how I could write this script using the 'grep' command?

1 - Searching inside a document for a matching string.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="document.doc"
ISSUE_1="Identifies inactive services"
if grep -c "$ISSUE_1" $FILE
then
    echo "There is an Issue"
else
    echo "There is NO Issue"
fi
```

2 - Searching inside a document for more than one string.

```
#!/bin/bash
FILE="document.doc"
ISSUE_1="Identifies inactive services"
ISSUE_2="Determines the percentage CPU idle time"
if [[grep -c "$ISSUE_1" $FILE]] || [[grep -c "$ISSUE_2" $FILE]]
then
    echo "There is an Issue"
else
    echo "There is NO Issue"
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a list of strings the easiest might be to put them in a file and use `-f` with `grep` to have it read a list of patterns from the file.  E.g., create a file called, say, `patterns`

```
Identifies inactive services
Determines the percentage CPU idle time
```

then use `grep` like

```
grep -f patterns -c "$FILE"
```

if you don't want a separate file, `grep` actually takes a pattern, not (necessarily) a fixed string, and that pattern can do `or` with a `|`:

```
grep -c "$ISSUE_1\|$ISSUE_2" "$FILE"
```

though if you just want to know if any matches were found you don't need to get the count and check that value, `grep` will tell you with its exit status, so you could use `-q` to supress the output

```
if grep -q -f patterns "$FILE"; then
    echo "At least one match"
else
    echo "No matches"
fi
```

If you want to see the actual strings that were matched you can use `-o` to output only the portions of the line(s) that match one of the patterns.  For example:

```
grep -f patterns -o "$FILE"
```

or

```
grep -o "$ISSUE_1\|$ISSUE_2" "$FILE"
```

As an aside as well, you should generally avoid using upper case for your variable names.  All caps are for system envrionment variables, and applications are [encouraged to use lowercase names](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/).

> Environment variable names used by the utilities in the Shell and Utilities volume of POSIX.1-2008 consist solely of uppercase letters, digits, and the  ( '_' ) from the characters defined in Portable Character Set and do not begin with a digit. Other characters may be permitted by an implementation; applications shall tolerate the presence of such names. Uppercase and lowercase letters shall retain their unique identities and shall not be folded together. The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications. Applications can define any environment variables with names from this name space without modifying the behavior of the standard utilities.

Comment: Thanks! +1 How would you go about outputting the specific string (or strings) matched as a echo message?

Comment: @kieran_mol I've updated the answer to show how to output the matched strings

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `-e` multiple times:

```
if grep -e issue1 -e issue2 file ; then
    do_something
fi
```